# Crop a man out of a 360 video

Tags: video

I'm making a 360 video, filmed with 2 180 degree spherical cameras back to back.  The problem is that the man holding the cameras shows up in the bottom section of the video.  With the software, (I am using Kolor Autopano Video) is there a way to crop a section out of the video?

Answer (score 1):

To do any cropping of video in Autopano Video, you will need additional software from Kolor: either Autopano Pro or Autopano Giga. That will allow you to click the edit button below the preview window to send it to the editing program and apply a crop.

Alternatively, you can render out your video from Autopano Video that includes the cameraman, and then make your crop in a video editing program like Premiere Pro or Final Cut (even iMovie and Windows Movie Maker may work). That video can still be rendered as 360 video.

Comment: Yes, but what shows instead of the man?  Sorry I'm a complete newbie to this.

Comment: Nothing shows instead of a man. Your request was for a crop. If you want to mask, that's a very different story, and given you don't have overlapping video (you mentioned two 180-degree cameras back-to-back) that could be quite difficult.

Comment: So, the idea would be to film without the man being in the way.

Comment: Most 360 videos I've seen simply accept that there is a cameraman. Check out nearly all examples on Littlstar, for example. If you don't want a cameraman in the frame, your camera will typically be stationary while the action occurs around it.